# Wrong weekdays from Calendar.getDisplayName()

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the weekday of a given date(e.g. birthday). Therefore, I'm using a Calendar object and calling the getDisplayName() method. But every time the method returns a wrong value, the weekdays are two days ahead. For example: Input: 23.11.2015 ->  Wednesday

Code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter your birthday. Format: DD.MM.YYYY");
String bday = s.nextLine();
String day_of_birth = bday.substring(0, bday.indexOf(".")); // start to first dot = day
String month_of_birth = bday.substring(bday.indexOf(".")+1, bday.lastIndexOf(".")); // between first dot and last dot = month
String year_of_birth = bday.substring(bday.lastIndexOf(".")+1); // last dot to end = year
Calendar birthday = Calendar.getInstance();
birthday.set(Integer.parseInt(year_of_birth), Integer.parseInt(month_of_birth), Integer.parseInt(day_of_birth));
String weekday = birthday.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
System.out.println("Weekday of birth: " + weekday); // wrong
```

Comment: Calendar months are 0 based, not 1 based. Thus January is 0 not 1.

Comment: 1- [`Calendar#set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int)) expects values in `year`, `month`, `date` order

Comment: Thanks @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [`Calendar#set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int)) expects values in `year`, `month`, `date` order
2. `Calendar` months are `0` based, not `1` based. Thus January is `0` not `1` (thanks HovercraftFullOfEels)

You should avoid using `String` parsing for these types of issues, instead, use a custom `DateFormat` to parse the input `String` and then utalise the `Calendar` class

```
try {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your birthday. Format: DD.MM.YYYY");
    String bday = s.nextLine();

    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(bday);

    Calendar birthday = Calendar.getInstance();
    birthday.setTime(date);
    String weekday = birthday.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
    System.out.println("Weekday of birth: " + weekday); // wrong    }
} catch (ParseException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which for an input of `24.11.2015`, outputs `Weekday of birth: Tuesday`

Of course, you could simply make use of the new Time API in Java 8, for example...

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter your birthday. Format: DD.MM.YYYY");
String bday = s.nextLine();

LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(bday, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"));
System.out.println("DayOfWeek = " + ld.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault()));
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, `Calendar` starts at `0` for January. But, Java also includes [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) which makes getting the week day (IMO) easier

```
String str = "23.11.2015";
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d.M.yyyy");
DateFormat outSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
try {
  System.out.println(outSDF.format(sdf.parse(str)));
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which outputs (as expected)

```
Monday
```